# Demystifying Spring framework

Tags: spring, frameworks, spring-mvc-test

With multiple ways to configure using either XML, Annotations or Java Config and the need to remember 100's of annotations and super-lengthy class-names, the Spring framework appears an extremely complex demon that cannot be understood. Moving from a structured programming paradigm where you are completely in control of the program flow and the code you write, framework driven programming is posing a serious challenge. Can anyone suggest an easy way to transition from structured programming to framework driven approach and also suggest the best way to understand and learn spring.

All resources available on the net have learning methods that keep hopping from one topic to another and seldom able to link different topics and explain subtle differences between scored of annotations that spring framework offers.

I have put out this note after investing two full weeks to just get the basics of "Why Spring" and "How to" using spring scouring hundreds of scattered articles on the net. So, I request all the experts out there not to cancel this question since it sounds very subjective with no straight answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you telling me there are frameworks that do not require remembering their classes or solutions that they provide?

The best way to learn Spring is to simply get into one by one module and see what it brings to the table. Their official examples are great and you can go through each of them in about 20-30 minutes.

Spring is big, but that is the reason why is it good because it provides many solutions to web issues.

Regarding annotations, why will simply remember which one is for what after enough repetition, the same as you remembered for loop.

As for "Why Spring" official spring site answers that question https://spring.io/why-spring

As for "How to" you can scroll through the following page https://spring.io/

Comment: spring.io has very cryptic language and uses too much of jargon to explain stuff. Not one of the best resources to start understanding spring...Can you suggest any other simpler literature that you have come across ?.                                                                  
Personally Python's Django framework seemed much more clear and easier to grasp.

Comment: It is not cryptic you are just new to Spring, it is completely normal that you are unfamiliar with the framework in the beginning, but you cannot really avoid "jargon" of the Spring if you want to learn it. There is no harm in googling "what is the scope of bean in spring" or whatever confuses you. Python is easier but it has the easiest learning curve in the industry when it comes to coding or anything else.
I personally started off with some Udemy courses that are for beginners, where they use simple words and simple examples. Just make sure you do not look at ones that are Spring+React+AWS

Comment: Also, book Spring in action 5th edition is really good, if you are a book guy.

Comment: Thank you Zawarudo ! I'll take your word on this.